# LED switching OFF randomly on brightness control

Tags: arduino, app-inventor

Hello I am trying to make a project in which I am trying to switch the LED on/off and control its brightness using bluetooth and double MOSFET module as PWM. I have used MIT APP INVENTOR to make the application. However, whenever the slider bar goes to zero and I try increasing the brightness one LED switches off automatically. The hardware is working completely fine and there is nothing wrong with connections. The only problem could be with the app or the arduino code.

```
const int ledPin = 9;      // the pin that the LED is attached to

void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the ledPin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

 pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);}

void loop() {
  byte brightness;

  // check if data has been sent from the computer:
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // read the most recent byte (which will be from 0 to 255):
    brightness = Serial.read();
    // set the brightness of the LED:
    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);
  }
  if(Serial.available()>0)
   {     
      char data= Serial.read(); // reading the data received from the bluetooth module
      switch(data)
      {
        case 'a': digitalWrite(13, HIGH);break; // when a is pressed on the app on your smart phone
        case 'b': digitalWrite(13, LOW);break;
            case 'c': digitalWrite(8, HIGH);break; // when a is pressed on the app on your smart phone
        case 'd': digitalWrite(8, LOW);break;// when d is pressed on the app on your smart phone
        default : break;
      }
        }
      }
```

[image: Application Front]
[image: Application Back]

EDIT: I found out the problem but dont know how to solve it. For example, the value of slider is from 0 to 255 so, if the value of "a" in ASCII code is 97 then at 97th position at the slider the value of "a" passes and the button for "a" switches the button.

Comment: if a value from slider equal to the ASCII code of the letters 'a','b','c','d' (97 to 100) is received by the second part of the loop then it is processed there

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: @Juraj indeed ASCII code is causing this problem but how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what is wrong with the Arduino Code. But I think this code will help.

```cpp
const int ledPin = 9; // This pin should be a pwm pin to control the brightness

void setup(){
  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the ledPin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

  if(Serial.available()>0){
     String data = Serial.readString();
     if(data == "a"){
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
     }
     else if(data == "b"){
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
     }
     else if(data == "c"){
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
     }
     else if(data == "d"){
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
     }
     else{
          int brightness = (int)data.toInt(); //Converting String data to integer
          analogWrite(ledPin, brightness); //Setting the LED brightness
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found out the problem but dont know how to solve it. For example, the value  of slider is from 0 to 255 so, if the value of "a" in ASCII code is 97 then at 97th position at the slider the value of "a" passes and the button for "a" switches the button.